# How to space Google Form margins in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-forms

I'm trying to add a Google Form to my mobile website. I want it to fill the full width of the screen. Here's my html:

```
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSc5jGXQ0hGA14kFnw4OGRE9aExMNtKNwHKWn-2CSUwti3CfbA/viewform?embedded=true" width="100%" height="95%" id="mobileContactForm" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" >Loading…</iframe>
```

The associated CSS is as follows:

```
#mobileContactForm{
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 5vh;
  margin-bottom: 5vh;
}
```

When I load this webpage on Google Chrome on my desktop with the window sized in a smartphone aspect ratio, it looks fine, properly taking up the full width of the webpage:
[Google Form on my desktop.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3wkYX.png)

However, when I load the same page in chrome on my phone (a Samsung Galaxy s8), there is huge white space on either side of the form, which appears really small for some reason:
[Google Form on my website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/13Yl9.jpg)

The width property on the iframe tag is set to 100%, so I'm not sure why it would be so different on my phone vs. my desktop. Does anyone know if there is a way to make the form properly sized on mobile, or why this is happening?

Thank you

Comment: Do you have the correct [meta viewport](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag) tag?

Comment: @Phix Ah, I didn't know that was a thing... clearly I don't have too much experience in HTML. I read the documentation and fixed it instantly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the `<meta>` tag with the `viewport` attribute? That should help.